# Why doesn't hover event work with on jquery method on bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

On the [bootstrap tabs documentation page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) I tried the following code:

```
$(".nav-tabs > li > a").on("hover focus", function(){ 
  alert();
});
```

The alert is shown when the tabs get focus but not when I hover over them. My question is:

- Why doesn't hover event work with `on` jquery method on bootstrap tabs?

Comment: Should work.... http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/xFW8t/2046

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki But when I implement the same on my website it doesn't work. i am using jquery 2.1.1. And why doesn't it work on bootstrap official website?

Comment: So try to find the best jquery version for your bootstrap or the inverse.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki What is the bug in jquery 2.1.1 and 1.12.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two reasons why this is not working

1) `alert()` is being suppressed on the website

2) `.on('hover')` is deprecated.

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

Try this code to see your desired result.

```
$(".nav-tabs > li > a").on("mouseover focus", function(){ 
  console.log("hello");
});
```

This does work, just not with the `alert` method. Try an alternative to get something to pop up on the screen that the website will allow.

Comment: #2 is right. It is deprecated for jquery versions 1.8 and removed for >1.9 http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes Thanks a lot.